# Toggle container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, toggle, gesture

How to achieve the custom toggle type of background in the image attached. I want to change the background color and icon changes onTap.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSNXV.png)

```
 GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        if(white == Colors.blue)
                                          white = Colors.white;
                                        else
                                          white = Colors.white;

                                        setState(() {

                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        width: 100,
                                        height: 100,
                                        color: white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can easily do would to set a variable for both the color and icon so that when you have the onTap occur it would change that variable and then setState. Below I have included a short bit of code to further show what I am trying to explain. If you have any issues implementing my concept with the code you already have written just let me know and show me some of your code and I can help!

```
Widget theCard() {
    Color theColor;
    IconData theIcon;

    return GestureDetector (
        onTap: () {
            if(theColor == Colors.blue) {
                theColor = Color.white;
                theIcon = Icons.check;
            }
            else {
                theColor = Colors.blue;
                theIcon = Icons.remove;
            }
            setState(() {
            
            })
        },
        child: Container(
            color: theColor, 
            child: Icon(theIcon)
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply separate that container in a stateful widget and use a variable in the state class to control whether the container is toggled or not.

Example:

```
var _isToggled = false
```

note that you can start it initially with true or false depending on your scenario, and then use this variable with conditions to decide the background color and the icon color.

Example:

```
color: _isToggled? Colors.blue : Colors.white
```

The last thing you should do is to toggle the value of that variable inside onTap method with calling setState() to reflect rebuild the widget with the new value of the variable which will change the evaluation result of the conditions to move to the other case.

Example:

```
onTap: (){
    setState(){
        _isToggled = !_isToggled;
    }}
```

With this approach, you will have a stand-alone widget that satisfies your desires!

Have a nice day!

Comment: Your answer is correct Sir, 
I have done this code but the color is not changing, Please check the code added to my question.

Comment: Double-check the logic in onTap method, I guess the variable named white is the variable that holds the color and you're checking if it's blue then assign white to it, and if it's white you are assigning also white and here's the flow, in else part you have to assign a blue color to it...

Comment: Thanks for your solution it works fine.