# Flutter_ implementation a raised button with two actions

Tags: flutter, dart

I am implementing a list of items and I want to have two styles for its list view. One style is to show it with a name and ID, and the other should be like a card with an image and other details.
I need a button to change between these two styles. How can I implement it?

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same logic discribed here in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63422552/11217945) to change the color of `Container` abon tapping to implement the logic of your senario.

If you needed further assistant, don't hesitate to ask in the comments here.