# customize bottom navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar

I'm working on a flutter project and I want to add a bottom navigation bar but I want to add a variable that show how many `BottomNavigationBarItem` it will be in this bottom navigation bar, for example if I set a value to 5 I Will have 5 `BottomNavigationBarItem` in my bottom navigation, if I change it to 3 I will have just 3. Is there a way to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare a variable to store the count of the items in the `BottomNavigationBar` and use it to generate the items.

If the variable is changing dynamically and you want to reflect that change to the `BottomNavigationBar` then set the widget containing the `BottomNavigationBar` as a `StatefulWidget` and follow the same concept in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63422552/11217945) to complete the rest of the task.